# Send SMS from GSM Modem witout getting target as SPAM from Carrier

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I will like to explain a little bit my situation before i ask my question so if you like to read it here is it:

On my country i have a small school just 150 students, i will like to send to each of them 5 SMS per day with different information so i don't have to use paper anymore, using internet is out of the question because most of my student don't have internet on there phones or in there homes but everyone has a phone that receives SMS, i searched all over the internet and most SMS providers charge approximately $/0.03 per SMS and that is just too much for me because at the exchange rate each SMS ends up costing me almost 0.10 at my currency, the SMS providers that offer SMS cheaper than that are blocked by my local phone providers so there SMS don't arrive at my local phones.

The math end up like this

> 150 students x 5 sms per day x 20 days per month x 0.1 per SMS = 1,500

approximate and that is way out of my budget.

On my country my providers offer free sms for a month for each SIM card that you buy and each SMS card cost 5.0 per month, so i whant to buy 6 CARDS and send SMS to 25 students per SMS card per DAY so i will have to pay each month only 30 and i will be able to send all SMS on my budget.

Now my question, i just want to know if using the SMS cards like this is possible, or i will get flag by my telephone providers. On my mind what i want to do is like giving each of my teachers one phone and make them use that phone to send SMS to there students 25 students per teacher, and there is nothing wrong with it, the only difference is that i will use the SMS cards on GSM modems and connect them to a computer so it will require only 1 computer instead of 6 phones, i will still pay the cost that my providers ask for each SMS card so on my mind i am not doing nothing wrong, but maybe one of you that read this question have a different point of view and with your answers you can help me to see other sides of the picture and help me find out if i am right and i am not doing anything wrong or I'm wrong.

Looking forward to your answers so i can continue with my project or forget all about it.

Comment: What country do you live in?

Answer (score 0):

It's curious to see that situation about of buying such amount of simcards. Well, the best scenario is that all of your students have the same cellphone operator but I guess that is not your case. For example, in my country there's a SMS packet of 10000sms that you can buy for almost 4USD but it covers SMS to mobile phones of the same operator you have.

The other way is to send SMS from the web (i.e https://www.sendatext.co/) but according to your situation it looks like everything must be done manually. There are many ways to solve this, but I hope you can consult that with your phone operator. Maybe they will offer a special price for you in order to support schools and education. Just saying. Have a nice day

Comment: I have talked to all the providers on my country and they do not offer bulk sms prices, the cheapest price that they offer is 0.1 or the other option that is "buy a SMS card and get free sms for a month to all operators", i have also tried https://www.sendatext.co/, and i get Sorry, you currently cannot send free SMS to. SIGN UP to send cheap text messages. so up to know i think i'm doing nothing wrong with the project that i post before

Comment: How far do they live? I know you said most of them don't have internet in their phones or home but what kind of phones do they have? Do they have android phones? If so, maybe you could turn your PC or a raspberry pi into chat server, create a long range wifi network using a wifi router, a wifi booster and high gain antena to cover long distances and talk with them freely using a a messenger or MQTT... in  my opinion

Comment: that is not an option, i don't have raspberry pi knowledge or long range wifi network using a wifi routers or antennas and not all have android phones, some of them have old nokia phones with no android or internet

Answer (score 0):

When you use SIM card to send messages, it means it is MO-MT (phone to phone).
In such cases no operator will filter messages in any case (as you pay).

Also, ask your operator, if they provide other way to send SMS thru application (usually thru API or SMPP).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation here:
http://www.notepage.net/manuals/pg/v8/server/html/index.html

You could try to use a program called PageGate to interface with your cellular modem to send SMS. Based on what you've described, you'll probably want to use the GUI Client to submit the messages that are then delivered using the cellular modem.

You'll first, you'll need to connect the modem to the PC and make a note of either the device's IP (if it receives messaging commands by TCP) or COM port. Once you have that information, you'll want to install PageGate, then go through the steps for 'Creating a GSM-AT' carrier as that's what lets thep rogram talk to the cellular modem.

Also, since you're going to be using a cellular modem, that also opens up the ability for the people who receive your messages to reply to them. If someone does reply to a message, that reply will come back to the cellular modem and sit in memory on the device. PageGate can be configured to check the device for replies and has a reply processing system, with optional scripting module, that can do  what you please with those replies (like write them as a file to a directory for record keeping, send them as an email to a predetermined email address or other SMS number, scan the reply for certain keywords and change who the reply needs to go to, etc).